# SQL: How do I combine two queries and get the same result?

Tags: sql

I want to combine Two different queries and get the result as shown below.

This Query gives me cancel counts w.r.t  vehicle_NAME

```
(SELECT 'bike' "vehicle_NAME", count(B.ORDER_ID) "cancel"
FROM TABLE A, CAR_BIKE B
WHERE A.vehicle_NAME IN ('bike')
AND A.ORDER_ID = B.ORDER_ID
AND B.Delivery_Status NOT IN ('0', '00')

GROUP BY A.vehicle_NAME

union 

SELECT 'car' "vehicle_NAME", count(B.ORDER_ID) "cancel"
FROM TABLE A, CAR_BIKE B
WHERE A.vehicle_NAME IN ('car')
AND A.ORDER_ID = B.ORDER_ID
AND B.Delivery_Status NOT  IN ('0', '00')
GROUP BY A.vehicle_NAME
union 
SELECT 'cycle' "vehicle_NAME", count(B.ORDER_ID) "cancel"
FROM TABLE A, cycle_RESP B
WHERE A.vehicle_NAME IN ('cycle')
AND A.ORDER_ID = B.ORDER_ID
AND B.Delivery_Status NOT  IN ('0', '00')
GROUP BY A.vehicle_NAME)
```

This BELOW Query gives me Success Delivered Counts w.r.t  vehicle_NAME

```
(SELECT 'bike' "vehicle_NAME", count(B.ORDER_ID) "Delivered COUNT" 
FROM TABLE A, CAR_BIKE B
WHERE A.vehicle_NAME IN ('bike')
AND A.ORDER_ID = B.ORDER_ID
AND B.Delivery_Status IN ('0', '00')
GROUP BY A.vehicle_NAME)  
union 
SELECT 'car' "vehicle_NAME",count(B.ORDER_ID) "Delivered COUNT" 
FROM TABLE A, CAR_BIKE B
WHERE A.vehicle_NAME IN ('car')
AND A.ORDER_ID = B.ORDER_ID
AND B.Delivery_Status  IN ('0', '00')
GROUP BY A.vehicle_NAME)
union 
SELECT 'cycle' "vehicle_NAME", count(B.ORDER_ID) "Delivered COUNT" 
FROM TABLE A, cycle_RESP B
WHERE A.vehicle_NAME IN ('cycle')
AND A.ORDER_ID = B.ORDER_ID
AND B.Delivery_Status  IN ('0', '00')
GROUP BY A.vehicle_NAME)
```

I want to combine both above queries and get the output as shown below:

```
vehicle_NAME | cancel | Delivered COUNT 
--------------------------------------
bike         | 20      | 35
car          | 10      | 34
cycle        | 45      | 45
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this answer:

```
SELECT "vehicle_NAME",SUM("cancel")"cancel",SUM("Delivered COUNT")"Delivered COUNT"
FROM(
    SELECT "vehicle_NAME","cancel",0 AS "Delivered COUNT"
    FROM
    (SELECT 'bike' "vehicle_NAME", count(B.ORDER_ID) "cancel"
    FROM TABLE A, CAR_BIKE B
    WHERE A.vehicle_NAME IN ('bike')
    AND A.ORDER_ID = B.ORDER_ID
    AND B.Delivery_Status NOT IN ('0', '00')
    GROUP BY A.vehicle_NAME
    union 
    SELECT 'car' "vehicle_NAME", count(B.ORDER_ID) "cancel"
    FROM TABLE A, CAR_BIKE B
    WHERE A.vehicle_NAME IN ('car')
    AND A.ORDER_ID = B.ORDER_ID
    AND B.Delivery_Status NOT  IN ('0', '00')
    GROUP BY A.vehicle_NAME
    union 
    SELECT 'cycle' "vehicle_NAME", count(B.ORDER_ID) "cancel"
    FROM TABLE A, cycle_RESP B
    WHERE A.vehicle_NAME IN ('cycle')
    AND A.ORDER_ID = B.ORDER_ID
    AND B.Delivery_Status NOT  IN ('0', '00')
    GROUP BY A.vehicle_NAME)D

    UNION ALL

    SELECT "vehicle_NAME",0 AS "cancel","Delivered COUNT"
    FROM
    (SELECT 'bike' "vehicle_NAME", count(B.ORDER_ID) "Delivered COUNT" 
    FROM TABLE A, CAR_BIKE B
    WHERE A.vehicle_NAME IN ('bike')
    AND A.ORDER_ID = B.ORDER_ID
    AND B.Delivery_Status IN ('0', '00')
    GROUP BY A.vehicle_NAME)  
    union 
    SELECT 'car' "vehicle_NAME",count(B.ORDER_ID) "Delivered COUNT" 
    FROM TABLE A, CAR_BIKE B
    WHERE A.vehicle_NAME IN ('car')
    AND A.ORDER_ID = B.ORDER_ID
    AND B.Delivery_Status  IN ('0', '00')
    GROUP BY A.vehicle_NAME)
    union 
    SELECT 'cycle' "vehicle_NAME", count(B.ORDER_ID) "Delivered COUNT" 
    FROM TABLE A, cycle_RESP B
    WHERE A.vehicle_NAME IN ('cycle')
    AND A.ORDER_ID = B.ORDER_ID
    AND B.Delivery_Status  IN ('0', '00')
    GROUP BY A.vehicle_NAME)E
    )D
GROUP BY "vehicle_NAME"
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want a simple aggregation query:

```
SELECT A.vehicle_NAME,
       SUM(CASE WHEN B.Delivery_Status NOT IN ('0', '00') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as num_cancelled,
       SUM(CASE WHEN B.Delivery_Status IN ('0', '00') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as num_delivered
FROM TABLE A JOIN
     CAR_BIKE B
     ON A.ORDER_ID = B.ORDER_ID
WHERE A.vehicle_NAME IN ('bike')
GROUP BY A.vehicle_NAME;
```